# Symfony 2 css 404

Tags: css, symfony, http-status-code-404

I have the following css file:

Path: \Canopy\AbcBundle\Resources\public\css\demo.css

This is the generated css: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bundles/canopyabc/css/demo.css" />

The error: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mydoamin.com/bundles/canopyabc/css/demo.css"

Server location: /var/www/src/Canopy/AbcBundle/Resources/public/css/demo.css

Why do I get a 404?

Comment: Did you run assets:install? Is the file present in the web directory?

Comment: No I did not. assets:install is not present in the web directory. The project has been manually set up without using composer.